# How to create a docker-compose.yml global file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a basic docker setup. The problem is that the ports are conflicting with already used ports from other projects.

For example, this `docker-compose.yml` uses port `3306:3306` for mysql, but I'm already using this port.

I can change the port to a different one, but I don't want to commit this changes by mistake and I don't want to ignore this file from git, in case i do need to make some permanent changes in the feature.

Is there a global `docker-compose.yml` file that will overwrite the current one? Either for individual projects or for all..

Any ideas?

Comment: see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `docker-compose.override.yml`.

For example, if you have two files like the below.

```
# docker-compose.yml
web:
  ports:
    - 8883:80
```

---

```
# docker-compose.override.yml
web:
  prots:
    - 9999:80
```

When you run `docker-compose up`, it will automatically read `docker-compose.override.yml` along with `docker-compose.yml` and then it will use port `9999:80` overwriting `docker-compose.yml` config.

(It will only overwrite what `docker-compose.override.yml` specifies, then use `docker-compose.yml` for the rest intactly)

Thus, by creating `docker-compose.override.yml` and ignoring it in `git`, you can achieve what you want.

For more detail refer [the document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

Answer (score 1):

When running multiple Docker applications on the same host machine, in order to avoid port conflicts you might want to consider not using fixed ports at all.

As written [in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports):

```
Either specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER), or just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen).
```

So, if you want to run two Docker containers which internally use port `3306`, this way both containers will get this port mapped to a random available port on the host machine (e.g. `32775` for the first container and `32776` for the second one).

To find out which external port got used, simply look it up via `docker ps -a`. For automated usage in an automation shell script, run something like

```
container_id=docker-compose ps -q <service name as in docker-compose.yml file>
echo $(docker port "${container_id}" | cut -d: -f2)
```

Alternatively, if you know the internal port and it is fixed, you can also run

```
docker-compose port <service name as in docker-compose.yml file> <private port>
```

The random port will change each time you remove and re-create your services. If this is not an option, e.g. because you need fixed URLs to communicate to your users, the next step could be to use a reverse-proxy in front of the containers. This way, you can access them via addresses like `my-service.my-host.some-domain` or `my-host/my-service`, no matter which random port got exposed.

I had some good experience using [traefik](https://traefik.io/) for this, the [nginx docker reverse proxy project](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) also works nicely.

If you are interested in going this way, there are plenty of tutorials available on the internet.